# SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault) c++ at fuction for pushBack() of list

Tags: c++

I catched segfault when run this code and can`t understand why.
If firstly i use one time push(&head,3); then segfault is not catched, but it works bad for true

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node *next;
};

void push(Node **head,int data)
{
    Node *tmp = new Node;
    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next = (*head);
    (*head) = tmp;
}
Node *getLast(Node *head)
{
    if(head == nullptr)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
    while(head->next)
    {
        head=head->next;
    }
    return head;
}
void show(const Node *head)
{
    while(head!=nullptr)
    {
        cout << head->data << endl;
        head = head->next;
    }
}

void pushBack(Node *head,int data)
{
    Node *last = getLast(head);
    Node *tmp = new Node;
    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next = nullptr;
    last->next = tmp;
}
int main() {
    Node *head=nullptr;
    **//push(&head,2);  /////if I use this then it works! but it not right.**
    pushBack(head,10);
    pushBack(head,2);
    pushBack(head,3);
    show(head);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to google it but it helpless.
How to solve this problem?

Comment: You're passing a null to `pushBack()`. `pushBack()` takes its null `head`, and passes it to `getLast()` which, of course, returns a `null`, so `last` in `pushBack()` gets set to null. So, what exactly about a segfault on `last->next = tmp;`, where `last` is a null, is unclear to you? What, specifically, about this simple sequence of events that results in undefined behavior, a segfault, you have a question about? As far as "how to solve this problem", it's simple: don't attempt to dereference a `null` pointer. (P.S. -- all of this should be easily visible in any debugger).

Comment: i bad understand, what part i have to edit to it works?please

Comment: Well, you need to figure it out yourself. What /do/ you want `pushBack` to do, if `getLast()` returns a null pointer? Do you `pushBack` to return, without doing anything? In that case, you seem to have demonstrated that you know how to use the `if` statement, so what exactly don't you understand? If you don't want to simply have `pushBack` return, in the event of a null pointer, then whatever exactly you want to do, you just have to do it. But I can't tell you what your program should do, that's something only you know.

Comment: if **getLast()** returns a nullptr then i have to create only one first element of list???I had to understant it?right?

Comment: You will need to decide that yourself. I can't tell you what your program should do, only you know what the requirements are, and what each function should do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the linked list is empty you have to modify head which requires to pass the reference of head. This should work:

```
void pushBack(Node **head,int data)
{
    Node *last = getLast(*head);
    Node *tmp = new Node;
    tmp->data = data;
    tmp->next = nullptr;
    if(last == nullptr)
    {
        *head = tmp;
    }
    else
    {
        last->next = tmp;       
    }
}
int main() {
    Node *head=nullptr;
    pushBack(&head,10);
    pushBack(&head,2);
    pushBack(&head,3);
    show(head);
    return 0;
}
```